# On create method calls twice in zxing

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, zxing

I am new to android. I had implemented a Tab in one app. In which i used Tab Host. In one of the Tab i had implemented Zxing for scanning Barcode.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Now when scanning is complete i had override on activity Result in my TabGroupActivity like.

```
@Override

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
 {

  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Now the problem is after scanning is complete its my Tab Activity callls twice.

Both `onCreate()` and `onResume()` method of Tab Activity and its child calls twice.I dont want it to call twice.

Thanks For Help

**First Edit**
Manifest File

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm" />

        <activity
            android:name=".TabsWithFragmentsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
```

**One more thing i just noticied that my app behaves different.
On tablet with version greater than 4.0 it works prefectly.
But with android tablet version 3.0 it works as i explained above. I am not sure which version Zxing needs if anybody can help?**

Comment: This is nothing to do with zxing. Android calls those methods. You have to figure out why two instances of the activity are being created.

Comment: @SeanOwen Actually the methods are called twics after i returned from Zxing

Comment: ... by Android. You are killing your own app or otherwise causing it to be spawned twice, or maybe misled by log info.

Comment: @SeanOwen I AM FEELING THAT BECAUSE I AM CALLING ZXING WITH GETPARENT() THAT WHY ITS ITS CALLING TWICE

Comment: paste the manifest file.

Comment: @AnupCowkur any suggestions. I had pasted manifest file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method onCreate can be called twice.

In android, when the available memory is less when running other application. It could kill your app, even when your app start another application. It will be even called when orientation changes (if android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" is not given for that activity)

As in your case, you are starting external application (Zxing) which may required more memory than available. In result of that, your application is killed but the activity stack with the save instances are maintained).

So when user comes back to your application. Android Framework run your application again with the same state and activity which will result in a call to your onCreate method (i.e the activity is again created).

To find whether it was recreated or run for first time. you can check savedInstanceState for null. If its null then it run for first time.

It could be also because of change in orientation, try adding android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" for activity in manifest.

Comment: This fixed my issue that has been plaguing me for months! Thank you! For anyone who runs into this issue when writing an Adobe AIR Native Extension, note that you have to add this to both your android project manifest and your activity tag in your app xml android manifest additions.

Comment: Thank you this helped my issue. Exactly like you describe is memory related. Question: what happens to private fields in that activity? Do they maintain their values when onCreate is called 2nd time?

Comment: all the private fields will not be saved. Its the developer duty to save all the fields required on onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and restore those fields using onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState) or onCreate(savedInstanceState)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your intent this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: I had used this but by using this you can be back to your application because it uses it built Functions and gives you result in with image and bar code.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed similar behavior when working with third party libraries, and often the simplest solution is a little hacky - but easy to understand and easy to implement. Simply keep track of whether or not `onCreate` has been called by using a `static boolean` value:

```
private static boolean hasBeenCreated = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!hasBeenCreated)
    {
        hasBeenCreated = true;
        //the rest of your onCreate code
    }
}
```